# Deploying Flask API to 'cloud run' result in error using gcloud run deploy

Tags: python, gcloud

I have a basic flask API to execute a python file.

Structure is as follows:

- app.py
- Dockerfile
- requirements.txt
- test.py

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, request
import subprocess
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/execute", methods=["GET"])
def execute():
    result = subprocess.run(["python", "test.py"], capture_output=True)
    return result.stdout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)),host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

**test.py:**
Python script that copies one document from a mongodb collection to another as a test.

The app runs on local machine.

Steps I followed in order to deploy to cloud run on gcloud:

1. docker build -t  .
2. docker tag  gcr.io//
3. docker push gcr.io//
4. gcloud run deploy  --image gcr.io// --platform managed --command="python app.py"

Error on step 4. When I look at the logs the error returned are as follows:
terminated: Application failed to start: kernel init: cannot resolve init executable: error finding executable "python app.py" in PATH [/usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin]: no such file or directory

Please note I am on a windows machine and the Path in the error looks like a Linux path so I am not sure where to go from here

Comment: To keep it simple, why not just use ```gunicorn```? In which case, replace the last 2 lines of your docker file with - ```CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 app:app```. This also means you have to add ```gunicorn``` to your ```requirements.txt```file and you can also remove the bit ```if __name__ == "__main__":``` from your ```app.py``` file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overriding the entrypoint of your docker image via the gcloud command.

You should not need to do so since it is already set in the `Dockerfile`.

Try changing the 4. step to:

```bash
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io// --platform managed
```

### Note

Looking at the error it seams that passing `--command="python app.py"` is changing the `CMD` command of your `Dockerfile` to something like

```
CMD ["python app.py"]
```

This is interpreted as a single executable called `python app.py` which is of course not found (since the executable is `python` and `app.py` is just an argument you want to pass to it.

Also as a sidenote I would suggest changing the last line of the `Dockerfile` to be an `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD`:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) for some details

Comment: Hi Matteo,

Thank you for your response.

I changed the Dockerfile as suggested, unfortunately the error still persist:

terminated: Application failed to start: kernel init: cannot resolve init executable: error finding executable "python app.py" in PATH [/usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin]: no such file or directory

Comment: Did you chenge your `gcloud deploy` command as well? As mentioned the change to the `Dokerfile` is optional and not the source of the error

Comment: Hi Matteo, apologies, yes I also changed the gcloud command line as suggested (with the required image name and project ID)

Comment: @EhanGreens Strange... Is the error still the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to successfully deploy to cloud run using the following, however when accessing the deployed API it returns a 404 error. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I switch to Waitress (Waitress is meant to be a production-quality pure-Python WSGI server).

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/run_script", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def run_script():
    result = subprocess.run(["python", "test.py"], capture_output=True)
    return result.stdout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

**test.py:**

```
df_AS = db.collectionName
#convert entire collection to Pandas dataframe
df_AS = pd.DataFrame(list(df_AS.find()))


newCollection.insert_many(df_AS.to_dict("records"))
```

this successfully deployed however the end point is not included in the url and have to be manually inserted at the end of the url. is this normal?